# AWS Cloudwatch Agent in Docker

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, ubuntu-16.04

I am trying to package AWS CloudWatch agent into docker container. The docker build runs into the following error -

> Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory
>
> unknown init system

Here is the snippet from Dockerfile -

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
RUN \
    apt-get -y update && \
    apt-get -y install wget && \
    apt-get -y install unzip
RUN \
    wget https://s3.amazonaws.com/amazoncloudwatch-agent/linux/amd64/latest/AmazonCloudWatchAgent.zip && \
    unzip AmazonCloudWatchAgent.zip && \
    ./install.sh
```

What is missing or wrong here?

Comment: My research on the topic led me to this question and provided explanations/solutions - https://serverfault.com/questions/607769/running-systemd-inside-a-docker-container-arch-linux. I am still working to run the agent in the container.

Answer (score 3):

I notice the documentation has different ways of installing, I wonder if they are both correct. I found another in the [EC2 guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/QuickStartEC2Instance.html#running-ec2-step-2) that a different method for installing on Ubuntu

```
RUN \
  curl https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-cloudwatch/downloads/latest/awslogs-agent-setup.py -O && \
  python ./awslogs-agent-setup.py --region us-east-1
```

Comment: Thanks Stephen. The link you referred will install the previous version of CloudWatch agent. I am trying to install the latest version - Unified CloudWatch agent. It can collect metrics as well.

Comment: ERROR: This script only supports python version 2.6 - 3.5

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that AWS has launched official docker image for the Cloudwatch agent on dockerhub and They are updating it frequently. I am late though, But It may help someone.

```
https://hub.docker.com/r/amazon/cloudwatch-agent
```

Comment: Did you find any documentation on how to use it ?